# Conectar java spring boot a 2 bases de datos SQLServer 2000 diferentes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, java-8, java-ee

Estoy usando java spring boot para conectarme a 3 bases de datos diferentes. Una de ellas es SQL server 2000. El problema es que necesito conectarme a una cuarta base de datos que también es SQL server 2000. Tuve muchos problemas para conectarme a la primer base de datos de SQLServer2000 hasta que note que en la funcion `thirdDataSource` el `prefix` de la anotación `@ConfigurationProperties` forzozamente necesitaba ser `spring.datasource.sqlserver` aunque en el `application.properties` yo tengo `spring.datasource.sqlserver8`.

Ahora necesito un nuevo `prefix` para la funcion `fourthDataSource` para la nueva base de datos, pero si pongo algo distinto a `spring.datasource.sqlserver` al parecer el driver de conexión no lo toma y no se conecta lanzando la excepción que anexo, pero si coloco `spring.datasource.sqlserver` eclipse me marca que ya se esta utilizando. Esta es mi clase:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MultiDatasourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "DSpostgres")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.postgres")
    public DataSource masterDataSource(Environment env) {
        final String datasourceUrl = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres.url");
        final String datasourceDriver = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres.driver-class-name");
        final String datasourceUsername = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres.username");
        final String datasourcePassword = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres.password");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(datasourceUsername).password(datasourcePassword)
                .url(datasourceUrl).driverClassName(datasourceDriver).build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "postgres")
    @Autowired
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("DSpostgres") DataSource dsMaster) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Bean(name = "dsPostgresSeguridad")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.postgres-seguridad")
    public DataSource secondDataSource(Environment env) {
        final String datasourceUrl = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres-seguridad.url");
        final String datasourceDriver = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres-seguridad.driverClassName");
        final String datasourceUsername = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres-seguridad.username");
        final String datasourcePassword = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.postgres-seguridad.password");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(datasourceUsername).password(datasourcePassword)
                .url(datasourceUrl).driverClassName(datasourceDriver).build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "postgresSeguridad")
    @Autowired
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate secondaryJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dsPostgresSeguridad") DataSource dsMaster) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Bean(name = "DSsqlServer8")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.sqlserver")
    public HikariDataSource thirdDataSource(Environment env)throws Exception {
        final String datasourceUrl = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver8.url");
        final String datasourceDriver = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver8.driverClassName");
        final String datasourceUsername = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver8.username");
        final String datasourcePassword = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver8.password");
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        config.setJdbcUrl(datasourceUrl);
        config.setUsername(datasourceUsername);
        config.setPassword(datasourcePassword);
        config.setDriverClassName(datasourceDriver);
        HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return hds;
    }
    @Bean(name = "sqlserver8")
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate tertiaryJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("DSsqlServer8") DataSource dsMaster) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
    }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Bean(name = "DSsqlServer9")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.sqlserver9")
    public HikariDataSource fourthDataSource(Environment env)throws Exception {
        final String datasourceUrl = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver9.url");
        final String datasourceDriver = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver9.driverClassName");
        final String datasourceUsername = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver9.username");
        final String datasourcePassword = env.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.sqlserver9.password");
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        config.setJdbcUrl(datasourceUrl);
        config.setUsername(datasourceUsername);
        config.setPassword(datasourcePassword);
        config.setDriverClassName(datasourceDriver);
        HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        return hds;
    }
    @Bean(name = "sqlserver9")
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate quaternaryJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("DSsqlServer9") DataSource dsMaster) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
    }
}
```

Cuando lanzó la aplicación con `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.sqlserver9")` en la función `fourthDataSource` esta es la excepción que me lanza:

```
    2023-10-11 11:22:17 - INFO  mypaquete.repositorioCheques.RepositorioChequesAPIApplication-logStarting{1}: - Starting RepositorioChequesAPIApplication using Java 1.8.0_311 on UTICT19 with PID 26764 (C:\Users\aahernan\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.14.1.RELEASE\repositorioInstitucionalCheques\target\classes started by aahernan in C:\Users\aahernan\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.14.1.RELEASE\repositorioInstitucionalCheques) 
2023-10-11 11:22:17 - INFO  mypaquete.repositorioCheques.RepositorioChequesAPIApplication-logStartupProfileInfo{1}: - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 
2023-10-11 11:22:17 - INFO  org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor-logTo{1}: - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable 
2023-10-11 11:22:17 - INFO  org.springframework.boot.devtools.env.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor-logTo{1}: - For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG' 
2023-10-11 11:22:18 - INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer-initialize{1}: - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http) 
oct 11, 2023 11:22:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting service [Tomcat]
oct 11, 2023 11:22:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
oct 11, 2023 11:22:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-11 11:22:18 - INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext-prepareWebApplicationContext{1}: - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1524 ms 
2023-10-11 11:22:19 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource-<init>{1}: - HikariPool-1 - Starting... 
2023-10-11 11:22:19 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase-getAndSetNetworkTimeout{1}: - HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (null) 
2023-10-11 11:22:19 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource-<init>{1}: - HikariPool-1 - Start completed. 
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource-<init>{1}: - HikariPool-2 - Starting... 
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase-getAndSetNetworkTimeout{1}: - HikariPool-2 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (null) 
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource-<init>{1}: - HikariPool-2 - Start completed. 
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext-refresh{1}: - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'DSsqlServer9': Could not bind properties to 'HikariDataSource' : prefix=spring.datasource.sqlserver9, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.sqlserver9' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource-close{1}: - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated... 
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource-close{1}: - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed. 
oct 11, 2023 11:22:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener-logMessage{1}: - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2023-10-11 11:22:20 - ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter-report{1}: - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.sqlserver9' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: spring.datasource.sqlserver9.driver-class-name
    Value: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 20:48
    Reason: The configuration of the pool is sealed once started. Use HikariConfigMXBean for runtime changes.

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Pero si coloco @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.sqlserver") en la función `fourthDataSource` eclipse me marca un error que dice:

> Duplicate `@ConfigurationProperties` definition for prefix
> 'spring.datasource.    sqlserver'

Y obviamente si quito las funciones `fourthDataSource` y `quaternaryJdbcTemplate` todo funciona correctamente.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?